# How can I format a date to remove preceding spaces and zeros using put_time()?

Tags: c++, date, datetime, c++11

My program parses a string representing a date formatted as YYYYMMDD and prints it in the form of dayOfWeek, Month Day, Year. For example, given the string `20131224`, the program should print `Sunday, December 24, 2013`.

The program I have written does just that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct tm tm;
    string s("20131224");
    if (strptime(s.c_str(), "%Y%m%e", &tm)) {
        cout << put_time(&tm, "%A, %B %e, %Y") << endl;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when given a string with a date with a preceding zero, like `20131204`, the output includes an extra space between the month and the day, like so: `Sunday, December  4, 2013`.

I know that if I use `%d` instead of `%e` then that space will be replaced with a zero, but that's not what I want either. I know that removing the space between `%B` and `%e` will solve the solution for single digit dates, but it doesn't work for double digit dates (as it will print `Sunday, December24, 2013`). And I know that I could use some sort of regex search to find and replace that double space, but surely there's a more straightforward solution to this.

**How can I remove both the preceding space and zero from a date formatted with `put_time()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cout << put_time(&tm, tm.tm_mday < 10 ? 
                      "%A, %B%e, %Y" : 
                      "%A, %B %e, %Y" ) << endl;
```

Comment: That works, thank you. But isn't it crazy that something as simple as printing a date without a preceding space or zero requires a hack like that?

Comment: this can't be true, omg omg